# Get data from an input inside a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, blur

Hi guys I'm trying to get the value of an input in my table, the problem is that I'm creating new rows dynamically by a button, these get the new ids and everything.

I'm getting the value by an `blur` event , but this one only gets the value when the main input loses the focus, but gets the data of the second input (if I've created a new one)

I want to get the data when the right input loses the focus

My table

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="tabla_transferencia">
    <thead>
         <tr>
             <th style="width: 80px">Codigo</th>
             <th style="width: 500px">Descripción</th>
             <th>Existencias</th>
             <th>Cantidad</th>
             <th>Costo/Unit</th>
             <th style="width: 40px">Total</th>
             <th></th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr id='row0'>
             <td>
                 <input type="text" id="txt_transferencia_codigo0" placeholder="Ingese el código"/>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <label id="lbl_transferencia_descripcion"/>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <label id="lbl_transferencia_existencias"/>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <label id="lbl_transferencia_cantidad"/>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <label id="lbl_transferencia_costoUni"/>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <label id="lbl_transferencia_total">
             </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<a id="btn_transferencia_nuevo" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Agregar</a>
<a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Row</a>
```

My js

```
var i = 0

$('#txt_transferencia_codigo' +  i).blur(function () {
  if ($('#txt_transferencia_codigo' + i).val() !== '')
    console.log($('#txt_transferencia_codigo' + i).val())
})

$('#btn_transferencia_nuevo').click(function () {
  i = i + 1
  console.log(i)
  $('#tabla_transferencia').prepend('<tr id=\'row' + i + '\'><td><input type=\'text\' id=\'txt_transferencia_codigo' + i + '\'></td></tr>')
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i mentioned in the comment, you must attach event handler each time after generating a new row.

```js
var i = 0

$('#txt_transferencia_codigo' +  i).blur(function () {
  if ($('#txt_transferencia_codigo' + i).val() !== '')
    console.log($('#txt_transferencia_codigo' + i).val())
})

$('#btn_transferencia_nuevo').click(function () {
  i = i + 1
  console.log(i)
  $('#tabla_transferencia').prepend('<tr id=\'row' + i + '\'><td><input type=\'text\' id=\'txt_transferencia_codigo' + i + '\'></td></tr>')
  var inputElement = $('#txt_transferencia_codigo' + i)
  attachBlurEvent(inputElement, i)
})

function attachBlurEvent(inputElement, i){
  $(inputElement).blur(function () {
  if (inputElement.val() !== '')
    console.log(inputElement.val())
})
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="tabla_transferencia">
    <thead>
         <tr>
             <th style="width: 80px">Codigo</th>
             <th style="width: 500px">Descripción</th>
             <th>Existencias</th>
             <th>Cantidad</th>
             <th>Costo/Unit</th>
             <th style="width: 40px">Total</th>
             <th></th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr id='row0'>
             <td>
                 <input type="text" id="txt_transferencia_codigo0" placeholder="Ingese el código"/>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <label id="lbl_transferencia_descripcion"/>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <label id="lbl_transferencia_existencias"/>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <label id="lbl_transferencia_cantidad"/>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <label id="lbl_transferencia_costoUni"/>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <label id="lbl_transferencia_total">
             </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<a id="btn_transferencia_nuevo" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Agregar</a>
<a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Row</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked, the second and third input get the right value when they lose the focus. But the first(main) input gets the data of the latest one

Comment: Forget it i just removed the var i in the first blur hahah thx

Comment: Yeah, global variables are not good for that reason :).Have you considered some class wrapper for a table?you can make one, what if you will use similar table in the future?it would ease your programming.Thats why there are so many libraries for jQuery.I encourage you to make your own.Cheers!